# Firefox and Libreoffice UI is broken

Tags: gtk, firefox, libreoffice

I had some troubles with my UI(like windows classic), can someone help me?

[image]

Comment: Have you taken any action with themes, or uninstalled any items?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure of why it could happens, but try the following :

Install Gnome Tweak Tools

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool
```

Then launch it :

```
gnome-tweak-tool
```

And make sure that everything in Appearance is set to elementary

[image]